# Symfony 4 undefined property error when using serializer

Tags: php, symfony4

While making an ajax call back to a controller to get comments from a database I'm getting the following error:

> Notice: Undefined property: App\Entity\ExceptionReport::$typeID

Comments are related to users which has a relation to exception report so I'm guessing that relationship is what is throwing the error. I wasn't sure if setting max depth was what I needed to implement, so I tried setting max depth on the users field in the comments class but got the same error.

```
public function getComments(CommentRepository $commentRepository, SerializerInterface $serializer) {

        $comments = $commentRepository->findAll();
        $encoder = new JsonEncoder();

        $defaultContext = [
            AbstractNormalizer::CIRCULAR_REFERENCE_HANDLER =>function($object) {
                return $object->getUsername();
            }
        ];
        $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, null, null,
            null, $defaultContext);
        $serializer = new Serializer([$normalizer], [$encoder]);

        return $serializer->serialize($comments, 'json');
    }
```